# Can't cancel Timer Task without creating another object in JDA

Tags: java, timertask, discord-jda

Mainly, I'm coding a discord bot that gets the price of any crypto (integrated with CoinMarketCapAPI) and returns the price to the user. I created a command that sends the price of Bitcoin on its closing time (12 am GMT or 9pm BRT) when triggered, but when I try to cancel it, the price still shows at given time.

I know what i'm doing wrong, but there's no clear solution in my mind:
When I call the alert class, it creates an object with its own timer, but I can't access the same object on another discord command, I have to create a different one.

```
//Command Handler Class
else if (command.equals("bitcoin-scheduled-alert-start")) {
            ScheduledAlert scheduledAlert = new ScheduledAlert(event.getTextChannel());
            scheduledAlert.start(LocalTime.of(21,00, 00));
            event.reply("The daily closing price of Bitcoin will be displayed from now on!").queue();

        } else if (command.equals("bitcoin-scheduled-alert-stop")) {
            ScheduledAlert disabledScheduledAlert = new ScheduledAlert(event.getTextChannel());
            disabledScheduledAlert.stop();
            event.reply("The current scheduled alert has been stopped!").queue();
        }
```

```
public class ScheduledAlert { //Bitcoin update at every candle close (12 am GMT [9 pm BRT])
    private final Timer timer;
    private TimerTask task;
    private final TextChannel channel;
    private final String symbol;

    public ScheduledAlert(TextChannel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
        this.symbol = "BTC";
        this.timer = new Timer();
    }

    public void start(LocalTime time) { //Getting the time from BotCommands parameter
        // Cancel the task if it is already scheduled (NOT WORKING)
        if (task != null) {
            task.cancel();
        }

        task = new TimerTask() { //Start TimerTask
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Started");
                CryptoPrice cmcApi = new CryptoPrice(symbol); //Get Bitcoin price
                double price = cmcApi.getPrice(symbol);

                NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
                String priceString = formatter.format(price);
                System.out.println((priceString));
                channel.sendMessage("The closing price of Bitcoin is " + priceString).queue();
            }
        };

        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")); //Sync date with time zone
        ZonedDateTime scheduledTime = ZonedDateTime.of(now.toLocalDate(), time, now.getZone());

        if (now.compareTo(scheduledTime) > 0) {
            scheduledTime = scheduledTime.plusDays(1); //If the command has been triggered after time in LocalTime, set it to next day at the set time
        }

        long delay = Duration.between(now, scheduledTime).toMillis();
        timer.schedule(task, delay, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
    }
     

    public void stop() {
        if (task != null) {
            task.cancel();
            task = null;
            System.out.println("Stopped");
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to access that same object?

Comment: This is not clear. In your `Command Handler Class` you are creating new instances of `ScheduledAlert` every time.  The code you marked as "Not working" will ALWAYS find `task==null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to keep created `ScheduledAlert` instances mapped to some unique identifier.

If i assume that text channel contains some unique and constant identifier (i mean you will never get different id for the same channel), you can use `Map<String, ScheduledAlert>`, where keys are `event.getTextChannel().getId()`.

Comment: Appreciate that, it worked just fine.